# How should I create my String variables? with class or Not?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question about the keeping String values. On the some flutter app tutorial videos, the guy keeping all `String` values in any dart file.
For example:

```
//Login Page
const String loginButton = 'LogIn';
const String registerQuestionText = 'Do You Have Any Account?';
const String registerButtonText = 'SingIn!';
const String usernameText = 'Username';
const String passwordText = 'Password';


//Register Page
const String emailText = 'Email';
const String bookText = 'Favorite Book';
const String passwordVerifyText = 'Password Again';
```

here on the other way, someones doing like that:

```
class ProjectKeys {
  static final String appBarTitle = "Hello";
  static final String buttonLabel = "Press The Button";
}
```

So, I'm confused about these usages. Which one should I use for clean code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```dart
class ProjectKeys {
  static final String appBarTitle = "Hello";
  static final String buttonLabel = "Press The Button";
}

if your using this you can use your String as ProjectKeys.appBarTitle
which ia object based approach
```

Comment: thanks for that usage. But I really wanted to ask is which one should I use ? I mean, if I used the second one(create dart file and just call variables) , will this correct? by the way thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes that is correct